# Why Dask shows FileNotFound Error while reading?

Tags: python, pandas, dask

I have encountered issues with dask which I cannot see in Pandas.
I have read small dataset in a notebook in google cloud.

[image]

df is saved as a dataframe and I now remove the source 'data_iris.csv' file and it shows filenotfound error.

[image]
How to overcome from it since I want to delete the file after saving into dataframe.

Comment: Question #1: Are you sure the file is the location specified by the URL? Question #2: Can you show your code leading up to this? For example, what is ```dd``` and how did you declare it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dask specialises in managing data sets that are bigger that your system's memory (and possibly computing in parallel across a cluster). It's operations are chunk-wise and lazy - things don't happen until you explicitly ask, and are not held in memory.

> df is saved as a dataframe

It is not. You have merely made a prescription for how to load that dataframe.

If you want to hold the data in memory, you could do

```
df = df.persist()  # hold in dask worker memory
```

or

```
df = df.compute()  # convert to Pandas
```

If you can do these things safely, then probably the data is too small for you to have bothered using Dask in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Dask works by providing access to a file on a disk. It is not designed to keep all the files/data into a memory that's why it is powerful than pandas for handling large data.

This is why it handles data larger than RAM as a single dataframe.